# How to send sms to a phone number using aws sns cli?

Tags: aws-cli

I am using the following command. Getting Authorization error.

```
aws sns publish --phone-number +91XXXXXXXXXX --message hello

An error occurred (AuthorizationError) when calling the Publish operation: User: arn:aws:XXX::XXXXXXXXXXXX:user/ABC-DEF-SNS is not authorized to perform: SNS:Publish on resource: +91XXXXXXXXXX
```

Other related sns commands are working. I can also able to send sms through a topic to a subscribed number.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question for AWS support and it's in no way related to devops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably your user `arn:aws:XXX::XXXXXXXXXXXX:user/ABC-DEF-SNS` does not have the required permissions to the `sns:Publish` API.

You can check using the IAM Policy Simulator at https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/

<sup>using policy simulator is explained in depth here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html</sup>